# jquery get img src onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble referring to an image on an onclick evet.

my example is that the "this" reference points to an element that has couple of images and i want to change a specific image.

```
<li  class = "header_det">
    <table  width="100%" style="font-size:14px;"> 
        <tr>                                      
            <td  width="10%" align = "right" rowspan = "2">text</td>
            <td width="80%"><img width="30" height="30" src="images/map_white_pin.png" ></a></td>                                                                               
            <td width="10%" align = "center" class = "header_pic"><img width="20" height="20"     src="images/route_det/down_arrow.png" ></td>                
        </tr>                                                                           
    </table>
</li>
```

The js code for the onclick event is this:

```
$(".header_det_map").click(function() {
    var img_type = $(this).attr(".header_pic img").attr("src") ;
    if(img_type == "images/route_det/down_arrow.png") { 
        $(this).attr(".header_pic img").attr('src', "images/route_det/up_arrow.png");         
    } else{
        $(this).attr(".header_pic img").attr('src', "images/route_det/down_arrow.png");
    }
});
```

this code doesn't work, and i have to use the this pointer because i have other

element with the same classes that i do'nt want to change.

Thanx

Comment: in your code you search `header_det_map` but in your html it's just  `header_det`. Is this correct or is this not the full html for the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you jquery is wrong : `.header_pic img` is not an attribute but an element of `.header_det_map`

Plus, you're HTML is a bit messy :

- You shouldn't have space between attribute name and value in your
  HTML
- There is closing `</a>` tags
- You should close `'<img />` tags

---

```
<li class="header_det">
    <table width="100%" style="font-size:14px;"> 
    <tr>                                      
        <td width="10%" align="right" rowspan="2">text</td>
        <td width="80%">
            <img width="30" height="30" src="images/map_white_pin.png" />
        </td>                                                                             
        <td width="10%" align="center" class="header_pic">
            <img width="20" height="20" src="images/route_det/down_arrow.png" />
        </td>                  
    </tr>                                                                           
    </table>
</li>
```

---

```
$(".header_det_map").click(function() {
    var img = $(this).find(".header_pic img"); // use a variable to store your image element in case you have to change the container class
    var img_type = img.attr("src"); // not necessary to store it, could be use as it in the if statement

    if(img.attr("src") == "images/route_det/down_arrow.png") { 
        img.attr("src", "images/route_det/up_arrow.png");         
    } else {
        img.attr("src", "images/route_det/down_arrow.png");
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you very much for the complete answer your code is correct

Comment: No need to close the img tag if it's html5

Answer (score 3):

I think this line:

```
var img_type = $(this).attr(".header_pic img").attr("src") ;
```

should be:

```
var img_type = $(this).find(".header_pic img").attr("src") ;
```

Comment: Also worth noting that the first line's first `.attr` will return `undefined` and thus the second `.attr` will throw an error